# PHP/mysql INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I want to insert some values into a mysql database and thought it can't be that hard. 
However I was wrong, maybe i am overlooking something simple.

This is my code:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*****", "*********", "usr_web633_3");
if(!$db)
{
  exit("Error: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO anmeldungen ('ID', 'vorname', 'name', 'gender', 'str', 'hausnummer', 'telefon', 'gemeinde', 'vegetarier'')
VALUES ('id', 'vorname', 'name', 'gender', 'str', 'hausnummer', 'telefon', 'gemeinde', 'vegetarier')";

$sqlinsert = mysqli_query($db, $sql); 

if($sqlinsert == true) { 
    echo "works!"; 
} 
else { 
    echo "doesn't work:(";
}
```

It doesn't work like it should.. the values are just placeholders.

Hope you can help!

Comment: You've got to use backticks around your column names, not single quotes.

Comment: Also, don't add values in your SQL use prepared statements. If you just add the values you are opening yourself to attack and may aswel just use mysql_ functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape column and table names with backticks.

```
INSERT INTO `anmeldungen` (`ID`, vorname, name, gender, str, hausnummer, telefon, gemeinde, vegetarier)
VALUES (1, 'vorname', 'name', 'gender', 'str', 'hausnummer', 'telefon', 'gemeinde', 'vegetarier')
```

And you had a quote too much at the last column name. Use a single backtick instead. But actually you only need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

And watch out for your column data types. You can't insert a string into a number column. So `id` can probably only be a number.

And if your `id` is an auto-increment value then you should not provide a value at all. Use `null` or leave the column from your insert statement completely.

```
INSERT INTO `anmeldungen` (`ID`, vorname, ...
VALUES (null, 'vorname', ...
```

Comment: @fredkid you have an option to use or not to use backticks on column names or table name. If your talbe name or column name is the same as a mysql reserved function then you use backticks if it's not you are okay without it

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong quotes for the columns. And there is a redundant quote at the end of your column list.

Try ` instead of ':

```
INSERT INTO anmeldungen 
   (`ID`, `vorname`, `name`, `gender`, `str`, `hausnummer`, `telefon`, `gemeinde`, `vegetarier`)
VALUES
   ('id', 'vorname', 'name', 'gender', 'str', 'hausnummer', 'telefon', 'gemeinde', 'vegetarier')
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop using values and start using prepared statements. Quote from the [PHP.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $district);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

And an update for the SQL on the prepared statement for inserting would be from [here](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-mysqli/)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE movies SET filmName = ?,
   filmDescription = ?,
   filmImage = ?, 
   filmPrice = ?, 
   filmReview = ? 
   WHERE filmID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('sssdii',
   $_POST['filmName'],
   $_POST['filmDescription'],
   $_POST['filmImage'],
   $_POST['filmPrice'],
   $_POST['filmReview'],
   $_POST['filmID']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Make sure you escape your fields correctly using the methods above! This however doesn't mean that you shouldn't validate the input.

Comment: @fredkid No problem, just don't want you to have a major security loop hole in your app!

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake in the line

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO anmeldungen ('ID', 'vorname', 'name', 'gender', 'str', 'hausnummer', 'telefon', 'gemeinde', 'vegetarier'')
```

there are two quotes after vegetarier.

correct it...it should work